# Running rosrun with gdb

Tags: ros, node, gdb, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running this in ros:

```
rosrun object_recognition_capture upload -i final.bag -n 'example' example --commit
```

object_recognition_capture is a package and I want to run it with all these options. How can I run it with debuger, if there is any possible way to do it? The problem is that this system is c++/python hybrid. Called `upload` program is a python code, but it calls c++ functions. So I can't use neither gdb nor pdb.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222530/running-rosrun-with-gdb/) by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is a Python script I guess `gdb` is not what you wan to be using. Instead, Python has `pdb` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

You could try

```
rosrun --prefix 'python -m pdb' object_recognition_capture upload -i final.bag -n 'example' example --commit
```

but this is just a guess. I have never started Python scripts this way with `rosrun`.

**Edit:** I guess for C++ code called from python scripts you could try to run the python executable with DGB, like described here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb

So best install the debugging symbols for your python interpreter and then try something like this:

```
rosrun --prefix 'gdb -ex run --args python' object_recognition_capture upload -i final.bag -n 'example' example --commit
```

Again, I haven't tried this, so its just a guess.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-12-16**:
Thanks, I can run this upload file with pdb, but there is another problem now, I edit my question (c++/python hybrid code).

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-12-16**:
Yes, gdb runs the program now, but it runs it whole, till its end. There is no opportunity to step through the program. I'm trying to figure out what to do about it.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2015-12-16**:
Yeah this is now not so much about ROS, but rather general Python / C++ debugging. You should be able to find lots of resources on the Web.

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-12-16**:
Yes, I'll try to find something, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using ROS *Indigo* or newer, you can use `--prefix` command line argument of `rosrun` ([ref](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#rosrun))

```
rosrun --prefix 'gdb -ex run --args' object_recognition_capture upload -i final.bag -n 'example' example --commit
```

On older ROS versions (or as an alternative solution), you can wrap your node in a launch file, then add `launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args"` to any `<node>` tag, as described in [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB).

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-12-15**:
Thanks for response. I tried it but gdb still says:

```
upload: not in executable format: File format not recognized
Starting program:  -i final.bag -n example example --commit
No executable file specified.
```

And it's true, upload is a python code from the package. So again, how to run it?

**Comment by [sykatch](https://answers.ros.org/users/24667/sykatch/) on 2015-12-15**:
The first line of the file is `#!/usr/bin/env python` and I already changed permissions `chmod 755 upload`, but gdb still says it's not an executable.